# Specific background for single nav link

Tags: html, css, hover, nav

Looking to find out how to change a single nav link to have a different background hover color than the others.

I've tried #nav #contact.hover and #nav #contact:hover to no avail.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="service"><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li id="parts"><a href="#">Parts</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearall"></div>
</div>
</html>

CSS:

.clearall {
    clear:both;
}
#nav {
    background:#333;
}
#nav ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:0px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}


#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:black;
}



Should change the contact element in the nav to have a background hover color of white
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have to get the selector right. I think you were having issues because your base style for hover is overly specific which trumps most overrides.

```
#nav ul li:hover a
```

...could easily be changed to simpler selector that would be easier to override, the use of ID's instead of classes adds to the specificity issue as well.

```css
.clearall {
    clear:both;
}
#nav {
    background:#333;
}
#nav ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:0px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav ul li:hover a {
    background-color:black;
}
#nav ul li#contact:hover a {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/100');
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="service"><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li id="parts"><a href="#">Parts</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearall"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the `:last-child` psuedo-class in your CSS.

Here's a codepen with the fix but I'll describe below what I did: https://codepen.io/Athys/pen/WBdYdZ

I added `:last-child` to the li selector since the "contact" link appears as the last list item (the last li). Then, I added a `:hover` psuedo-class to the a selector and give it a different hover color and text-color than the other a elements. Hope this helps.